# How write a regex in c to find whether string is hex

Tags: c, regex, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to write a program to find whether a give string is hex or not.So the given string must contain only character in between 0-9,A-F and a-f.How can i accomplish this using C?
The program i tried is give below but the regex pattern is not working well.What will be the error in this pattern?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[a-fA-F0-9]+$", 0);
        if( reti )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
            //exit(1);
        }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "ABC123defG", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                //exit(1);
        }

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How* is it "not working well"? That regex seems fine to me.

Comment: Even if i gave 1234 to match it says no match

Comment: I know you asked for a C solution, but I wanted to call out a very simple solution in C++:

bool IsHexString(const char* psz)
{
    return std::regex_match(std::string(psz), std::regex("[a-fA-F0-9]+"));
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `REG_EXTENDED` in the flags argument to regcomp. If you don't, you end up with "basic" regular expression syntax, which doesn't include the `+` operator, amongst other things.

It's slightly surprising that "basic" regular expressions still exist, never mind being the default. But that's backwards-compatibility for you.

Comment: Thankyou very much that worked.Am not that much comfortable with regular exp.Is this expression ok `regcomp(&regex, "^[a-fA-F0-9]+$", REG_EXTENDED);` Whats the significance of + operator

Comment: @ganeshredcobra: yes, it is fine. `+` is the "Kleene plus": one or more repetitions of the thing it follows. `*` (the "Kleene star") would be zero or more repetitions; i.e., it would match an empty line. Basic regex have * but not plus; extended have both. `man 7 regex` should explain all the possibilities.

Comment: @rici my apologies.  I meant to reply to "Whats the significance of + operator" and I am not sure how I happened to put your name.  No offense intended.

Comment: @ganeshredcobra you should find a tutorial or introduction to regular expressions. Google will find them for you. One place to start: the Wikipedia page. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression